# DIfferent view width for phones and tablets

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, tablet, screen-size

Trying to avoid creating a specific layout for tablets. Maybe there is some solution to achieve such results as on the images with ConstraintLayout or something like that

Screen for a phone:

[image]

The same screen for a tablet:

[image]

Comment: You can try with a `maxWidth` parameter based on the view hierarchy you have. You can nest 2 `ConstraintLayout` where the outer one is full width and the internal one is centered and constrained per your needs

Comment: Use _ConstraintLayout_. Center the two _EditTexts_ using constraints to the start and end of the layout and constrain the labels to the start of and _EditText_. This assumes that the test entry fields are the same width.